# Jump cursor X number of lines up or down

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is it possible in Visual Studio/Resharper to jump the cursor x number of lines with a shortcut (Something like Ctrl+Up/Down Arrow) to make going up or down a bit faster/easier? I know you can use ctrl+g to specify a line number you want to go to however that isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Page Up / Page Down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign a shortcut to it:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineDown");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for.